# How to continue the process of uploading which is started in foreground even after application got killed android?

Tags: android, service, retrofit, retrofit2, background-process

I am working on project in which there is an requirement of uploading files to server. For uploading big files it will take much time to upload. To avoid this situation I thought of uploading files from background. For uploading files from background I used service inside of that service I am using Async task for uploading files the problem is when uploading got started and if remove the application means killing the service also getting stopped. How to solve this issue. Please find my code snippet below of what I had done up to now

```
public class BackgroundService extends Service {

ProgressRequestBody.UploadCallbacks callbacks = new ProgressRequestBody.UploadCallbacks() {
    @Override
    public void onProgressUpdate(int percentage) {
        Log.i("percentage", "" + percentage);
    }

    @Override
    public void onError() {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFinish(int finished) {

    }
};


@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    String filePath = intent.getStringExtra("filePath");
    final int studentId = intent.getIntExtra("studentId", 0);
    int documentType = intent.getIntExtra("type", 0);
    uplodeBackground uplodeBackground = new uplodeBackground();
    uplodeBackground.execute(filePath, String.valueOf(documentType), String.valueOf(studentId));
    return START_STICKY;
}

class uplodeBackground extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Void> {
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... strings) {


        ApiInterface apiInterface = ApiClient.getClient().create(ApiInterface.class);
        File file = new File(strings[0]);
        //RequestBody progressRequestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("multipart/*"), file);
        ProgressRequestBody progressRequestBody = new ProgressRequestBody(file, callbacks);
        MultipartBody.Part[] part = new MultipartBody.Part[2];
        part[0] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("file", file.getName(), progressRequestBody);
        part[1] = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("documentTypeId", strings[1]);
        RequestBody mStudendId = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("text/plain"), /*String.valueOf(studentId)*/strings[2]);
        Call<JsonObject> call = apiInterface.uploadFile(part, mStudendId);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<JsonObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<JsonObject> call, Response<JsonObject> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    if (response.body().get("status").getAsInt() == 200) {
                        Log.i("test", "Uploaded successfully..........");

                    }
                }
            }


            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<JsonObject> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.i("test", "Failed successfully..........");
            }
        });
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

this is how i am starting service

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(AddVideoFragment.this, BackgroundService.class);
                intent.putExtra("filePath", SelectedFile.getPath());
                intent.putExtra("studentId", NewRegistartionController.initializeNewRegistrationController().basicDetailsModel.getStudentId());
                intent.putExtra("type", doumentTypeId);
                intent.putExtra("contentId", objects[1].toString());
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
                    startForegroundService(intent);
                } else {
                    startService(intent);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

You call your AsyncTask class in forground service.Only forground service not kill when application in background.

Comment: you want me to call service like context.startForegroundSerice()

Comment: because from lollipoup ,Android os close all background service by default.You can follow this link. https://codinginflow.com/tutorials/android/foreground-service

Comment: I just changed my code please check how i had tried

Comment: try it ,  ContextCompat.startForegroundService(context, intent);

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206521/discussion-between-ashok-and-ganesh-surya-n).